# AppendChild given plain text want HTML using only pure JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to build a dynamic table using Javascript. The problem that I'm facing is I have strings only, no html in the `<td>`. How can I solve this?

My snippet works in my code. But I have the Problem, that if in events[][] for example is

```html
"<a href="#">link</a>"
```

it is not given out as html but in text. So on display I see the hmtl code, not the link.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i += 1) {

                    var row = document.createElement('tr');
                    for (var y = 0; y < events[i].length; y += 2) {

                        var cell = document.createElement('td');


                        var text = document.createTextNode(events[i][y]);
                        cell.className = 'left_table_head';

                        cell.appendChild(text);
                        row.appendChild(cell);

                        var text = document.createTextNode(events[i][y + 1]);

                        var cell = document.createElement('td');
                        if (y == 0) {
                            cell.className = 'right_table_head';
                        }
                        if (events[i][y + 1] === '') {
                            cell.className += ' empty';
                        }
                        cell.appendChild(text);
                        row.appendChild(cell);

                        document.getElementById('mobile-responsive').appendChild(row);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: What do you  mean by `I have strings an not html in the td`?

Comment: Can you share `events` ?

Comment: Could you add `events` object example definition, so that this snippet works and we can see the problem. Just two-three rows, there is no need in the whole original object.

Comment: `document.getElementById('mobile-responsive').appendChild(row);` should come after `inner-loop`

Comment: @Rayon may not be, what if he wants to insert for every pair in events[i]

Comment: basically `var row = document.createElement('tr');` has to be inside 2nd for loop

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didnt' aksed exactly what I want.
My snippet works in my code. But I have the Problem, that if in events[][] for example is "<a href="#">link</a>" it is not given out as html but in text. So on display I see the hmtl code, not the link.

Comment: Please post an answer if you've solved your issue; don't edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var events = [
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"],
    ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"]
]

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i += 1) {


    for (var y = 0; y < events[i].length; y += 2) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var cell = document.createElement('td');


        var text = document.createTextNode(events[i][y]);
        cell.className = 'left_table_head';

        cell.appendChild(text);
        row.appendChild(cell);

        var text = document.createTextNode(events[i][y + 1]);

        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        if (y == 0) {
            cell.className = 'right_table_head';
        }
        if (events[i][y + 1] === '') {
            cell.className += ' empty';
        }
        cell.appendChild(text);
        row.appendChild(cell);

        document.getElementById('mobile-responsive').appendChild(row);

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<table id="mobile-responsive">

</table>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

I am assuming you are trying to insert into empty table. Else you need to use `inserRow()` Example is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The scripts run before the pages load. Try using the function in window.onload function.
Assuming that the table tag in html has been given the id as 'mobile-responsive'.

JS:

```
      window.onload = function() { 
         var events=[["dfd","<p>Hello</p>","333"],["1","22","333","4444"],["1","<a href='#'>link</a>","22","4444","55555"],["<a href='#'>link</a>","22","333","<a href='#'>link</a>","55555","666666"]];
         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i += 1) {

            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var y = 0; y < events[i].length; y += 2) {

                var cell = document.createElement('td');


                 if(events[i][y] != undefined){
                   var str=events[i][y] ;
                   var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
                   var flag= Array.from(doc.body.childNodes).some(node => node.nodeType === 1);
                   if(!flag){
                       var text = document.createTextNode(str);
                   }else{
                    var text = document.createElement('div');
                    text.innerHTML = str;
                  }
                }else{
                var text = document.createTextNode("");
                }
                cell.className = 'left_table_head';

                cell.appendChild(text);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                if(events[i][y + 1] != undefined){
                   var str=events[i][y + 1] ;
                   var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
                   var flag= Array.from(doc.body.childNodes).some(node => node.nodeType === 1);
                   if(!flag){
                       var text = document.createTextNode(str);
                   }else{
                    var text = document.createElement('div');
                    text.innerHTML = str;
                  }
                }else{
                var text = document.createTextNode("");
                }


                var cell = document.createElement('td');
                if (y == 0) {
                    cell.className = 'right_table_head';
                }
                if (events[i][y + 1] === '') {
                    cell.className += ' empty';
                }
                cell.appendChild(text);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                document.getElementById('mobile-responsive').appendChild(row);

            }
        }
        };
```

Updated the answer depending on comment. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didnt' aksed exactly what I want.
My snippet works in my code. But I have the Problem, that if in events[][] for example is "<a href="#">link</a>" it is not given out as html but in text. So on display I see the hmtl code, not the link.